# Unable to use JuliaCall package

Tags: r, julia, tex

I'm new in all this.

I had installed in **R** the packages needed for Julia, i.e (**JuliaCall**), in **Julia terminal** I had install also other package called -
**using Pkg
Pkg.add("RCall")**

**when I try to run my Rstudio with the code there is a message saying the following:**

```
Error in .julia$cmd(paste0(Rhomeset, "Base.include(Main,\"", system.file("julia/setup.jl",  : 
  Error happens when you try to execute command ENV["R_HOME"] = "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.1";Base.include(Main,"C:/Users/apach/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/JuliaCall/julia/setup.jl") in Julia.
                        To have more helpful error messages,
                        you could considering running the command in Julia directly
```

I had also download Texliv from LaTeX to get it with PDF format.
this is the original code:

[image]

Comment: **JuliaCall** is currently broken. Maybe it works with an older version of Julia.

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue with JuliaCall at the moment- see [this open Github Issue](https://github.com/Non-Contradiction/JuliaCall/issues/201).

The solution at the moment (from the thread) is to install this forked version:

```
devtools::install_github("https://github.com/JackDunnNZ/JuliaCall/tree/patch-1")
```

After installing that, it should work again:

```
library(JuliaCall)
julia_setup()
julia_eval("1+1") # [1] 2
```

Comment: This answer is not useful and the proposed solution is incorrect, at least on Linux Debian. Actually, it killed my R process ("R Session Aborted"), something that very, very few packages have ever done.

Comment: @HansW. how odd! You might want to post about that on the JuliaCall github page, depending on if it's an issue with the fork or JuliaCall itself

Comment: @HansW. I'm happy to try helping to debug the problem with you if you want. The answer is helpful for others (see the thread), but clearly something is different on Linux (or your distro, or just your computer, unclear)

Comment: This command does not work, the link does not exist